# Is MainWindow initialized with itself in qt5?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I try to learn qt 5, but dont understand one thing.
Qt creator makes these two files by default:

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;    
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)    // <!-- what does it do?
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

I dont understand this: `ui(new Ui::MainWindow)` in constructor? I know it initializes ui pointer, but to what? To itself? So basically, does it mean that `MainWindow` is initialized with itself, or maybe has reference to other instance of `MainWindow`? If so, is it some c++ programming pattern or methodology? Does it have a name, so I could read about it myself.

Many thanks in advance for explanation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not `MainWindow`, it's `Ui::MainWindow` - not the same class. Classes in `Ui` namespace are classes automatically generated by qmake (and friends). This class contains code that initializes and allows you access to widgets on your form - ones you created in graphical Qt designer.

This class is contained in file included in second line in your cpp file:

```
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
```

Comment: I see. So basically, class `Ui::MainWindow` is totally different (it has its own definition in  "ui_mainwindow.h") than MainWindow. So one more question. As an end user I should only work with the MainWindow class? Therefore I dont need to change/modify the `Ui::MainWindow`?

Comment: @FirstTimer12 Correct. The `Ui::...` class is just a "translation" of what you edit in the designer (it contains the widgets as members, and it has code to set them up the way you did it in the designer, including layout and more). It's created when compiling your code, so you shouldn't modify it (it would be overwritten when recompiling your code).